# How does android.enableBuildCache=true functions in new Android Studio 2.2?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-2.2

I have recently migrated to new Android Studio 2.2 among many other features I also came across **android.enableBuildCache=true** to decrease build time.

My question is that *how is this helping my builds go faster and what exactly is being cached* ? Because I have actually **noticed an increase in initial build time** which has made me question whether I should use it or not. If somebody could explain me the inner functionality and what exactly is cached and in what conditions then maybe I will be able to fine tune this caching and speed up my builds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this link shows all the details: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/build-cache

here are some relevant parts:

> ... build cache feature that can speed up build times (including full
>   builds, incremental builds, and instant run) by storing and reusing
>   files/directories that were created in previous builds of the same or
>   different Android project.
>
> Currently, the build cache contains only pre-dexed libraries; in the
>   future, we will use it for caching other types of files as well.

when your build time increased, then maybe

- I guess this could be normal for the first build after activating the cache
- it's a bug of this experimental feature: in this case, please [file a bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Android%20Studio%20bug)
- the cache was not used at all:

  > Step 0
  >   Ensure that **android.dexOptions.preDexLibraries** is either **not
  >   set or set to true**; otherwise the libraries will not be pre-dexed and
  >   therefore the build cache will not be used.
  >
  > Step 1
  >   **android.enableBuildCache=true**
  >
  > Step 2
  >   Build your Android project and **check** the following locations to see whether the build cache took
  >   effect. By default **the cache-dir** is
  >   /.android/build-cache. The final pre-dexed files
  >   are stored in
  >   /build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug and
  >   /build/intermediates/pre-dexed/release. You
  >   need to run the command line to see the “pre-dexed” directory; if you
  >   click the “Run” button from the Android Studio menu, you will not see
  >   this directory as it will be deleted.
  >
  > Note: If you are using Multi-dex with minSdk >= 21, the dexed files
  >   will be stored directly into the
  >   /build/intermediates/transforms/dex directory
  >   without being stored in /build/intermediates/pre-dexed.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this.